# How to give a container root permission (serviceaccount) before starting the build

Tags: openshift, openshift-3

Openshift does not allow to run containers as root, but you can do this by creating a service account:

```
oc adm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -z useroot
```

and then patching the deployment configuration, this will consequently deploy a new replication controller version with the new changes, is it possible to create the service account and include it in the following command:

```
oc new-app --name=test --docker-image=myregistry.com/test:latest
```

and have the service Account name included in the above command to avoid having a new version of the app or if there's any other possibility to foresee this root permission error and decrease the security for the pod to run as root without patching or redeploy the app

Comment: You shouldn't need a service account...last I played around with this, you should be able to give your user the permission (just leave off the `-z` and use your username)...and that should be enough to make it work. But, honestly, it's been awhile since I did this. At least maybe it'll be something worth testing?

Comment: Not you own user, but the ``default`` service account of the project. Doing that is not really recommended though as then everything in the project could run as ``root``. Best practice is to use a separate service account. See https://cookbook.openshift.org/users-and-role-based-access-control/how-can-i-enable-an-image-to-run-as-a-set-user-id.html

Comment: Thank you all for your response I’ll make sure to try the provided solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will and Graham has already provided great comments for you,
so I suggest additional practical details of them as follows.

If you grant `anyuid` `scc` to `default` `ServiceAccount` before `oc new-app`, the `test` pods are going to run as `root` permission without version change.

```
# oc adm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -z default
# oc new-app --name=test --docker-image=myregistry.com/test:latest

# oc rollout history dc/test
deploymentconfigs "test"
REVISION    STATUS      CAUSE
1       Complete    config change

# oc rsh dc/test id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

OR

If you need to specify the custom `ServiceAccount` name, you can extract `oc new-app` yaml and create resources after add `serviceAccountName: useroot` element to it. These steps also do not change the deployment version.

```
# oc create sa useroot
# oc adm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -z useroot
# oc new-app --name=test --docker-image=myregistry.com/test:latest -o yaml --dry-run > test.yml
# vim test.yml
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: apps.openshift.io/v1
  kind: DeploymentConfig
  ...
  spec:
  ...
    template:
      spec:
        serviceAccountName: useroot
  ...
# oc create -f ./test.yml
imagestream.image.openshift.io/test created
deploymentconfig.apps.openshift.io/test created
service/test created

# oc rollout history dc/test
deploymentconfigs "test"
REVISION    STATUS      CAUSE
1       Complete    config change

# oc rsh dc/test id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, this is actually a good approach for the problem I have, thanks for the help!